# How to use shared_ptr in LuaJIT FFI/C++ binding?

Tags: c++, c++11, binding, lua, luajit

I am working on creating a Lua binding to another C++ project. After some investigation, LuaJIT FFI seems to be the best choice to achieve that goal. I really benefit from the lua-user mail list archive [1] and another related slide [2]. Actually a Hello World sample is done here [3] and any suggestions for improvements are welcome.

Currently I am trying to introduce `shared_ptr` to this sample so that I won't need to care about garbage collection issue. But due to my poor experience on both Lua and LuaJIT, the Lua script always return `Segmentation fault` and I even do not know how to debug that. The code snippets are listed as following and wish you talented guys can give me some practical advice.

This is `hello.cpp` and the command I use to create the library is `g++ -std=c++11 -shared -fPIC -o libhello.so hello.cpp`.

```
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

class Hello {
    public:
        const char* World()
        {
             return "Hello World!\n";
         }
};

typedef shared_ptr<Hello> pHello;

extern "C" {
    pHello Hello_new(){
        return pHello();
    }

    const char* Hello_World(pHello self){
        return self->World();
    }
}
```

This is the `hello.lua` with running command `luajit hello.lua`.

```
ffi = require('ffi')
ffi.cdef[[
    typedef struct pHello pHello;

    pHello Hello_new();
    const char* Hello_World(pHello);
]]
hello = ffi.load('hello')

hello_index = {
    World = hello.Hello_World
}
hello_mt = ffi.metatype('pHello', {
    __index = hello_index
})
Hello = hello.Hello_new

hello = Hello()
io.write(ffi.string(hello:World()))
```

- [1] http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2011-07/msg00492.html
- [2] https://speakerdeck.com/igdshare/introduction-to-luajit-how-to-bind-cpp-code-base-using-luajit-ffi
- [3] https://gist.github.com/huxuan/929e4abc7e8883f4bce47b02faf54db5

Comment: I don't know how LuaJIT even accepts your cdef; `struct pHello` doesn't have a definition, so LuaJIT can't possibly know how big it is and how many bytes `Hello_new` returns. In any case, don't directly expose a `shared_ptr` in a C API - there's no good way of making it work in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things don't work like you expect them to do.

First of all, your C++ code is flawed: The call `return pHello()` returns an empty `shared_ptr` with no managed object (say: null pointer). If you want to create a new object, call `return std::make_shared< Hello >()`.

Apart from that, using a `shared_ptr` does not help you regarding garbage collection. The reference counting done by the smart pointer relies on the destructor being called, a C++ mechanism. As the FFI library interfaces with C code this won't happen no matter how you wrap it up to pass it to LuaJIT (your compiler should have warned you about the use of `extern "C" together with a class-typed return type).

The standard way (if you want to rely on garbage collection) is to let the `__gc` metamethod call a function doing the `delete` on the C++ side. This is the C way: You allocated a resource in your function call, you are responsible to free it afterwards.

I'd recommend to write a simple wrapper around your class, perhaps using pure Lua API first to learn the basics. Move onto wrapping `shared_ptr` later, when you have shared objects and don't want to do the reference counting yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.